# How to de duplicate rows in spark dataframe based on custom logic?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark dataframe which looks as follows:

```
Id,timestamp,index,target
id1,2020-04-03,1,34
id1,2020-04-03,2,37
id1,2020-04-04,1,31
id1,2020-04-05,1,29
id2,2020-04-03,1,35
...
```

The dataframe is partitioned in the cluster on the "Id" column.

I want to make sure that there are no rows with duplicate values of "Id" and "timestamp".
If there are duplicate entries then I want to choose the row with lower value of "index".
(If there are duplicate rows with same entries in "Id", "timestamp", "index"; then choosing any of the rows is fine)

So above dataframe after de duplication should look as follows:

```
Id,timestamp,index,target
id1,2020-04-03,1,34
id1,2020-04-04,1,31
id1,2020-04-05,1,29
id2,2020-04-03,1,35
...
```

Note that the second row <id1,2020-04-03,2,37> has been dropped.

Since the dataframe is already partitioned on "Id" - I am hoping to find a way in which there is no communication required across partitions thus making the operation very efficient.

Answer (score 0):

```
val df = Seq(
  ("id1", "2020-04-03", "2", "34"),
  ("id1", "2020-04-03", "3", "34"),
  ("id1", "2020-04-03", "1", "37"),
  ("id1", "2020-04-03", "5", "34"),
  ("id1", "2020-04-04", "1", "31"),
  ("id1", "2020-04-05", "1", "29"),
  ("id2", "2020-04-03", "1", "35")).toDF("Id", "timestamp", "index", "target")

df.sort("index").dropDuplicates("Id", "timestamp").orderBy("timestamp").show()
+---+----------+-----+------+
| Id| timestamp|index|target|
+---+----------+-----+------+
|id1|2020-04-03|    1|    37|
|id2|2020-04-03|    1|    35|
|id1|2020-04-04|    1|    31|
|id1|2020-04-05|    1|    29|
+---+----------+-----+------+
```

You can sort by index then use drop duplicates to achieve and keep lower index.

Comment: I guess this works, but it does not, as the question asks, uses the fact that the DF is already partitionned by id upfront, and that this could be used to avoid the shuffle your `sort` does. The way I see it (but I haven't given it enough thought), changing your sort to be by `id, timestamp, index` in that order would be more efficient. The DF being partitionned by id, this should not suffle, and then the dropDuplicates would naturaly keep the lowest index.